# Typescript equivalent of inline JavaScript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, typescript, asp.net-core, vuejs2

This may be self-evident but I'm not finding any example that informs what I'm trying to do (maybe I'm just doing it wrong). I'm adding Vue to an existing ASP.NET Core MVC application and adding the JavaScript statements directly to the page works but when I try to migrate to a TypeScript file nothing happens.

The JavaScript is:

```
new Vue({
    el: "#productPage",
      data: {
        isLoading: true
    },
    methods: {
    },
    mounted () {
        console.log("mounted()");
        this.isLoading = false;
    }
});
```

This works as expected. Migrating the code to a TypeScript file `productPage.ts`:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

new Vue({
  el: "#productPage",
  data: {
      isLoading: true
  },
  methods: {
  },
  mounted () {
      console.log("mounted()");
      this.isLoading = false;
  }
});
```

Which generates:

```
(function (factory) {
  if (typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object") {
      var v = factory(require, exports);
      if (v !== undefined) module.exports = v;
  }
  else if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
      define(["require", "exports", "vue"], factory);
  }
})(function (require, exports) {
  "use strict";
  Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
  var vue_1 = require("vue");
  var HonestyBox;
  (function (HonestyBox) {
      new vue_1.default({
          el: "#productPage",
          data: {
              isLoading: true
          },
          methods: {},
          mounted: function () {
              console.log("Mounted !!!!");
              this.isLoading = false;
          }
      });
  })(HonestyBox || (HonestyBox = {}));
});
//# sourceMappingURL=productPage.js.map
```

And including the generated javascript file `productPage.js`:

```
<script src="~/js/productPage.js"></script>
```

This does nothing. Stepping through the debugger neither of the conditions in `function(factory)` are satisfied. The console tells me `You are running Vue in development mode.` but the included JavaScript fails to run. The `tsconfig.json` used to generate the JavaScript file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "umd",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "wwwroot/js"
  },
  "include": [
    "Typescript/**/*"    
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

Using `"module": "commonjs"` results in `ReferenceError: exports is not defined`. I was hoping to avoid having to use Browserify or Webpack.

Comment: You probably shouldn't add the `import` statement, unless you add a bundler like Webpack

Comment: Please show generated `productPage.js` file

Comment: Added the generated javascript. I was hoping to avoid adding a bundler - is there any way to "import" vue without using `import`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you add Vue in a separate script tag before your productPage.js.

This means that you can't import Vue in your TypeScript file, but you need to declare Vue so the module just assumes that Vue has been loaded already (outside of your TS module).

```
declare const Vue; // this replaces your Vue import statement
```

If you want to add a bundler later on, you need to remove your script tag which loads Vue and only go the modular approach:
Vue needs to be imported with an import statement so the bundler knows that he has to include all of Vue.
You will then have one single JS file (or if your bundler splits it: multiple JS files).

Comment: Thanks @Peter that's exactly what I'm looking for.